# is there a way to set methods using method without pointers in c++?

Tags: c++

is there a way to set methods using method without pointers?

```
void (*_method)();

void setMethod(void (*method)()) {
    _method = method;
}

void getMethod() {
    _method()
}

void aMethod() {

}

main() {
    setMethod(aMethod);
    getMethod();
}
```

Is there a way to do this without the pointers? just straight up variables? i know I can do something like this without pointers:

```
void callSomeMethod(void (method)()) {
    method();
}
```

But can the whole thing above that be done without them?

Comment: A pointer is a variable.

Comment: You want to set pointers to methods without using pointers to methods?

Comment: yes, kind of like what you would do to a non-pointer variable..

Comment: i guess the point is that I did't want to return the pointer to a method in that getMethod method. I wanted to return a copy of it

Comment: You wanted to return a copy of the method?

Comment: yes! I don't want people messing with that method using that getter..

Comment: maybe you should return a const pointer then?

Comment: `void callSomeMethod(void (method)())` *does* use pointers. A function type appearing in a parameter list automatically becomes a pointer to that function  (similar to how an array type automatically becomes a pointer to the element type of the array).

Comment: If it's just the ugliness of function pointers that's putting you off, use a `typedef` like this: http://ideone.com/kWOEzV

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid using pointers you can always use references.

```
void callSomeMethod(void (&method)())
{
    method();
}
```

This has the benefit of preventing null pointers from being passed to `callSomeMethod()`.

Comment: You can have a reference to a function? Cool.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use `std::function` and `std::bind` to do this.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: @EJP: I think yes, but it's more convenient to use, since all the dirty work is going under the hood